# Audio Frequency is not converting to Uint8 in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

If you understand “BitFrequencyConverter” or converting `[Uint8]` into sound frequencies `[Int]` and back.

When I convert the frequency to Uint8, it covers correctly, but when I convert Uint8 back to frequency, I get an empty string.

The main function is calculateFrequency()

Please what am I doing wrong?

I have tried rewriting the SenderTask class (that is responsible for decoding and encoding the text that is to be converted to frequency from Uint8)

Here is my function

```swift
func calculateFrequency(byteArray: [UInt8]) -> [Int] {
        var resultList: [Int] = []
        let isDataModulo = byteArray.count * 8 % numberOfBitsInOneTone == 0
        var currByte: UInt8 = 0x00
        var currShift = 0

        for i in 0..<byteArray.count {
            let tempByte = byteArray[i]

            for j in (0..<8).reversed() {
                if currShift + j + 1 + (byteArray.count - (i + 1)) * 8 < numberOfBitsInOneTone && !isDataModulo {
                    let temp = getBit(check: tempByte, position: j)

                    if temp == 1 {
                        resultList.append(startFrequency + padding)
                    } else {
                        resultList.append(startFrequency)
                    }

                    continue
                }

                let temp = getBit(check: tempByte, position: j)
                currByte = currByte << 1

                if temp == 1 {
                    currByte = currByte &+ 0x01
                }

                currShift += 1

                if currShift == numberOfBitsInOneTone {
                    let currFreq = specificFrequency(sample: currByte)
                    resultList.append(currFreq)
                    currByte = 0x00
                    currShift = 0
                }
            }
        }

        return resultList
    }
```

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with getting an empty string? Your problem description doesn't really describe the problem you are having with the posted code. Please clarify your question. Please better explain what issue you are having with the code. What is an example of input and what is the expected output versus the actual output?